# Parsing date in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-1.9, ruby-1.9.3

I need a date of birth as a plain text in Ruby on Rails application. So here is the main part of a code I'm using to do it

```
   if @date_of_birth_as_text.present? and Date.parse(@date_of_birth_as_text).nil?
      errors.add :date_of_birth_as_text, "cannot be parsed"
    end
```

So it makes everything to a date. Look at it, it's quite odd

```
1.9.3p194 :002 > Date.parse("12 12 addd")
 => Sun, 12 Aug 2012 
1.9.3p194 :003 > Date.parse("12 12 october")
 => Fri, 12 Oct 2012 
1.9.3p194 :004 > Date.parse("12 13 october")
 => Sat, 13 Oct 2012 
1.9.3p194 :005 > Date.parse("13 13 october")
 => Sat, 13 Oct 2012 
1.9.3p194 :006 > Date.parse("13 13 2012")
 => Mon, 13 Aug 2012 
1.9.3p194 :007 > Date.parse("13 01 2012")
 => Mon, 13 Aug 2012 
1.9.3p194 :008 > Date.parse("10 01 2012")
 => Fri, 10 Aug 2012 
1.9.3p194 :009 > Date.parse("10 01 2010")
 => Fri, 10 Aug 2012
```

I want to change it a little bit. I want a date in format either`"MM (any delimeter or not) dd (any delimeter or not) YYYY"` or  `"dd (any delimeter) MM (any delimeter) YYYY"` can be parsed. Or something like that, but not "12 12 addd".

How can I reach it?

P.S I saw gem chronic, please don't suggest me to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Date.strptime:

```
1.9.3-p194 :017 > Date.strptime( '08-29-2012', '%m-%d-%Y' )
 => #<Date: 2012-08-29 ((2456169j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Documentation: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime